# Keras - get number of samples used to build the model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a Keras model for image classification saved as an HDF5 file. Is it possible to trace back the number of samples (images) used to create the model?

Answer (score 2):

No, this information is not saved anywhere in the model file.

Comment: @rassar This directly answers the question, the answer is literally just "no".

Comment: No means No the question was correctly answered by Dr Snoopy